# show comments in grid view using ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datagridview, webmethod

If user hits show comments button with class comments, pop up opens up. Want to populate this pop  up (gridview is content of the pop up) with comments for the Item. 
html :

```
<div class="pop-up-comments">
        <div class="pop-up-wrap-comments">
            <div class="edit-form">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CommentText" HeaderText="CommentText" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"  />
                    </Columns> 
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="user-controls">
                <button class="close-popup btn btn-danger">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
$(document).on("click", ".comments", function () {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var id = clicked.attr("data-id");
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin.aspx/ShowComments",
        data: id,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnedstring = data.d;
            alert(returnedstring);
        }
    });
    $('.pop-up-comments').addClass('show-popup');
});
```

c#

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string ShowComments(string id)
            {
                return id;
            }
```

Breakpoint on this WebMethod never fires. Why ? And how to send array of comments into datagridview ??

Comment: If you open the browser's developer tools, is there an HTTP 500 on the page method POST?

Comment: @KarlAnderson yes. 
http://i.imgur.com/GNKm1OZ.png

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods accept and return JSON, so you need to convert the data you are sending to JSON via `JSON.stringify`, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".comments", function () {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var id = clicked.attr("data-id");
    alert(id);
    var dataToSend = {
        id: id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin.aspx/ShowComments",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnedstring = data.d;
            alert(returnedstring);
         }
    });
    $('.pop-up-comments').addClass('show-popup');
});
```